# Legend wont display in stacked bar graph where the 2 series of values are numerical

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar graph with 2 numerical values and the bars are stacked on top of eachother.  I would like to display a Legend that indicates the description of the 2 colors.  Here it is my code but its not displaying.  Any help from anyone I would be greatful for.

```
ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x = Xaxis)) + 
    ggtitle("My Title")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold"))+
    geom_col(aes(y = v1), fill ="red")+
    geom_col(aes(y = v2), fill="blue")+
    labs(y= "Amount", color ="Legend")+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

From the above code the legend does not display

Comment: Without access to your data to be able to run your code or seeing any of your output, it's unclear what you're looking at and how you're trying to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
As I already mentioned in the comments you may consider another strategy with long format, but with your format you are in conflict with showing the legend of fill argument and getting the correct colors.

1. If you put the `fill` argument outside of `aes` no legend will be shown but you get the correct colors.
2. If you put `fill` argument inside the `aes` then the legend will be shown but the colors will be not as desired -> this is because you're basically generating a new factor variable and a legend.

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1675

With the `mtcars` dataset:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) + 
  ggtitle("My Title")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold"))+
  geom_col(aes(x = cyl, y = disp, fill ="red"))+
  geom_col(aes(x= cyl, y = mpg, fill="blue"))+
  labs(y= "Amount", color ="Legend")+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue'), labels=c('disp', 'mpg'))
```

[image]

**First answer:**
try this:

```
ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x = Xaxis)) + 
  ggtitle("My Title")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold"))+
  geom_col(aes(y = v1, fill ="red"))+
  geom_col(aes(y = v2, fill="blue")))+
  labs(y= "Amount", color ="Legend")+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

your code with the mtcars data set:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x = cyl)) + 
  ggtitle("My Title")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold"))+
  geom_col(aes(y = disp, fill ="red"))+
  geom_col(aes(y = mpg, fill="blue"))+
  labs(y= "Amount", color ="Legend")+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))
```

gives:
[image]

Comment: This causes me an error because too many close brackets....

Comment: ok. `geom_col(aes(y = v2, fill="blue"))`

Comment: I removed ` scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)`.  And note, If I am correct this behaviour is because fill is outside the `aes`. So I just put it in the `aes` of `geom_col()`

Comment: Thank you it worked! but now how do I adjust the colors?

Comment: I think you have to rethink your strategy. Best is to bring your data in long format then you can call the fill argument in the first line and you don't need two geom_col(). If you want I show with the mtcars dataset.