# Adding a legend + slope of trend line in ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot and the following code I created the plot below:

```
df_have %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, num_visits)) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue") +
  ggtitle("Number of Customers Visiting Store by Month") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fit = num_visits ~ date, se=F, color="red") +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Number of Visits")
```

[image]

However, I am wondering how to:

1. add a legend differentiating between the blue line (number of visits) and red line (line of best fit) and
2. annotate this chart with the equation of the red line in the form of `y = mx + c`

Thanks!

Edit: Sample data

`df_have`

```
   num_visits     date
1      19.825 2021.000
2      25.025 2021.083
3      27.950 2021.167
4      25.425 2021.250
5      29.575 2021.333
```

Comment: Could you provide a little data. `dput(df_have)`

Comment: @TarJae sure, added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** One way could be using `ggpmisc` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

my.formula <- y ~ x
df_have %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, num_visits)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = "blue")) +
  ggtitle("Number of Customers Visiting Store by Month") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fit = num_visits ~ date, se=F, aes(color="red")) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula, 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE) +  
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Number of Visits")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'red'), labels=c('num_visits', 'y = mx + c'))
```

[image]

**First_answer:**
You mean this kind of output?

```
df_have %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, num_visits)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = "blue")) +
  ggtitle("Number of Customers Visiting Store by Month") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fit = num_visits ~ date, se=F, aes(color="red")) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Number of Visits")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'red'), labels=c('num_visits', 'y = mx + c'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is almost it. Though I want the y=mx+c to be annotated on the graph, similar to here: https://l4labs.soton.ac.uk/tutorials/excel/images/excel22.jpg
The Legend for the red line would actually just say "Line of best fit" but the line itself would have the formula for the line of best fit as determined by `geom_smooth(method = "lm")`, e.g., `y = 2 + 0.043x` would appear above the red line, or on the main chart somewhere.

Comment: ah oK no problem I will update.

Comment: Have a look here to understand colors and legend <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093892/legend-wont-display-in-stacked-bar-graph-where-the-2-series-of-values-are-numeri/71093916#71093916>

Comment: Thanks for that link. By the way I tried to do this on my system. The equation gets added, but the legend does not show up. There are no error messages, could you think of a reason why?

Comment: If you want to show the legend, then the rule of thumb is to put your colour or fill argument inside `aes()`. The drawback with this procedures is that you won't get the desired colors or fills, so you have to add them manually with `scale_fill_manual` or `scale_color_manual`. At the beginning it is confusing but it turns out obvious with time!

Comment: Ah, yes you are right! I forgot to amend the code to include `aes()`. Thank you so much!